# Is there an SQL query equivalent for Disable Related Foreign Keys option available in the Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

TLDR: Is there a script or SQL query to mimic the functionality "Disable the related foreign keys"

I am working on a project which uses multiple tables and some tables have multiple foreign keys too.
I need to truncate the tables often and for disabling the related foreign keys I need to use the options every time which is a tedious process. Is there an SQL query equivalent for that I can run it any time I want?

Comment: It's rather unclear what are you trying to do (you can always join without filtering, just ignoring foreign keys). You should explain in more detail what "tedious process" you use and what results you expect.

Comment: Sorry my question is vague, but I got a solution for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing it frequently, then create a **script** which will

- disable foreign key constraints
- truncate tables
- enable constraints

so you'd just run a script and watch it doing the job.

---

Or, if tables contain not-that-many-rows, **delete** them (instead of truncating tables); then you won't have that problem.

Comment: I know how to truncate table using SQL. But I'm not sure how to disable/enable related foreign keys using SQL query.

Comment: One by one, I'm afraid, using ALTER TABLE statement, e.g. `alter table emp disable constraint fk_emp_dept;` To enable them, just replace `disable` with `enable`.

Comment: I found the answer. Oracle SQL Server shows the script which is running in SQL tab of the window which asks for confirmation. I copied it and made a script.

Comment: Good. I'm glad you made it.